# Как в <img> поменять картинку при определенной ширине экрана?

Tags: html, css

В background-image можно поменять через media запросы, а как это сделать с тегом img? Например, для мобильников подставить картинку поменьше, чтобы они не грузили изображения по 1000px и более. Возможно ли решение через css или надо как-то по-другому?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
             elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

Дока: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Поддержка браузеров: https://caniuse.com/#search=srcset

Answer (score 6):

Вы можете использовать следующий подход, переключая изображения с помощью media-queries:

```html
<picture>
 <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/800" media="(min-width: 800px)" />
 <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/400" media="(min-width: 400px)" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320" />
</picture>
```

Answer (score -1):

Через img вы уже отправили запрос. Для таких вещей делается мобильная версия сайта, которая отдает именно контент для мобильных устройств.

Comment: Не забывайте про адаптивную вёрстку